# How to know a generic type T if it has an appropriate constructor for use?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a doubly linked list which has sentinel nodes as its head and tail, say this class named `List`. `Node` is a private structure in `List`. This class has a private method `Init` for initializing the head and tail node, which is invoked in the constructors of `List`.

```
template<typename T>
class List {
public:
    List() {
        Init();
    }
    ...

private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
        
        // Constructors
    };

    size_t size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    void Init() {
        // Codes arise some problem if instances of T have no default constructor.
        head = new Node;
        tail = new Node;
        head->prev = nullptr;
        head->next = tail;
        tail->prev = head;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
};
```

Now, the question is that, if instances of `T` have no default constructor, I cannot create sentinel nodes using `head = new Node;` and `tail = new Node;`. The `new` operator always allocates a piece of memory and constructs it. When constructing the `Node` object, it must use some constructor of `T` to initialize the `data` field in `Node`.

Is there a way to inspect which constructors (except the copy and move construtors) of `T` I can use to construct the variable `data` of type `T`? Or can I only initialize the `prev` and `next` fields in `Node`, leaving the `data` field uninitialized?

Comment: If `T` doesn't have a default constructor then you'll get a compile time error.

Comment: Even if you know what constructor it has how would that help you? Say you find there is the `T(X, int, int, bool, Y, Z)` constructor. What would you do with that information? It's practically useless. Remember you are in a generic context. The right thing to do is: never ever initialize a `T` object unless the user of your api explicitly requested it. You don't know what `T` is. Maybe even if it has a default constructor, it's a very expensive operation.

Comment: Is `Init()` intended to create a `List` that contains `0` elements?  If that is the case, you likely want your design of `Init()` to also create zero `T`s.

Comment: `struct Node { virtual ~Node() = default; Node* prev; Node* next; }; struct DataNode : Node { T data; };`

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate nodes for `head` and `tail` to point to, they have the same lifetime as the owning `List`

Comment: btw, *why* are you choosing to have two sentinel nodes? `head->prev` and `tail->next` will always be `nullptr`, and they don't contain `data`, so they are really just `Node *`s

Comment: @Caleth I think Having two sentinel nodes can make the logic of removing and inserting nodes more consistent, eliminating some special cases.

Comment: @Eljay nice solution that works well :)

Comment: @bolov yes. the real solution is to refactor the `Node` class, separating `data` from `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a type T that should follow the concepts you are requiring.

In your case, you want it to be default constructible. If the instantiator of the template doesn't provide a T the complies, it'll get a large template error.

You could add a static_assert to your code, to provide a better message (and to provide it earlier, if your method ain't directly used)

You could use: `static_assert(is_default_constructible_v)`.
More variants exist, if it shouldn't throw ..., see [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible)

In C++20, you could use concepts as well to restrict T. I'm not fluent in them, so I'll leave it to you to find the correct syntax.

There are other solution, like storing std::optional, or using variadic arguments on your init function in order to construct T.
In which case you might want to restrict the code using [std::is_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible). [std::aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) could also work if you don't mind placement news. All depends on what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: In my original code `head = new Node;`, my aim is not really to construct `T` using its default constructor or other constructors, but I just need construct such a `T` successfully, or I cannot use the idea of sentinel nodes. I don't know what constructor I can use in `T` to finish this construction. Say `class F {public: F(const F& x) {} F(F&& x) {}};`, this class is pathological, but `std::list<F> list;` is completely legal. I also want to achieve this in my codes. Refactoring `struct Node` is a solution, idk if there are other solutions.

Comment: In that case you'll need optional or aligned_storage

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds good, for simplicity sake I suggest you use std::optional

Comment: yes, after changing `T data` to `std::optional<T> data`, it also solved my problem, only that it needs C++ 17 compiler.

Comment: I hope it to be available for you, you could also do with a (unique) pointer, though that requires more memory allocations

Comment: I appreciate your help, sir. I am happy to know more solutions on a problem.